# Что докупать для создания умной квартиры на raspberry pi и openhab?

Tags: raspberry-pi, умный-дом

**Из имеющего в наличии** [**raspberry pi 3b+**](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/), более менее дружу с Java по этому в приоритете управлять квартирой с [**OpenHab**](https://www.openhab.org), но также могу рассмотреть варианты [Domoticz](https://www.domoticz.com) и [Home Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io)

**Необходима поддержка xiaomi *(различные датчики)*, ikea, philips *(лампы)*, ТВ и стиралку *(скорее всего от Samsung)*.**

Но не знаю что еще необходимо докупить до малины чтобы иметь возможность связываться и управлять ZigBee и *Z-wave* *(не приоритетно, на будущее)* устройствами, в сети нету достойной информации все очень поверхностно, из того что нашел:

1. **[Elelabs ZigBee](https://elelabs.com/products/elelabs_zigbee_shield.html)** - по отзывах не очень, вечные проблемы и потеря связи, сейчас даже не продается, что то новое будут выпускать
2. **[RaspBee](https://phoscon.de/en/raspbee)** или **[ConBee 2](https://phoscon.de/en/conbee2)** - вроде популярное решение, но все что находил в сети завязано на Domoticz
3. **[CC2531](http://www.ti.com/tool/CC2531EMK)** - нужно шить, но не знаю все-ли мои устройства будет поддерживать *(К примеру TV и Стиралку)*

но все выше перечисленное вроде как работает только с ZigBee, есть *[Samsung Smartthings](https://www.smartthings.com)* который работает с разными протоколами *(ZigBee, Z-wave)* но весь контроль осуществляется с их приложения и не знаю можно ли перенести все в OpenHub, а также какое будет поведение устройств и датчиков в случае отсутствия интернета

*Что докупить до малины чтобы управлять всеми zigbee и в подальшем z-wave устройствами ?*

Comment: Я бы для каждого источника тока (розетки выключатели и т.д. ) и тех мест где необходимо поставить датчики провел бы витую пару и в дополнение оставил бы пустое место рядом с этими местами размером с розетку, это даст возможность ставить любого типа датчики и всякого рода реле,и не парится за связь, в витой паре минимум 4 провода, можно подклчить что хочешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ТВ сейчас обычно управляется через WiFi. Аналогично и со стиралками.

Датчики -- Xiaomi, Ikea -- и лампы Philips (если не ошибаюсь) работают по ZigBee. Учитывая, что самый распространённый в России именно Xiaomi, считаю разумнее всего ориентироваться на него. У Xiaomi есть неплохой хаб, который прекрасно умеет работать с другими устройствами по ZigBee: https://xiaomi-smarthome.ru/aqara-hub/

Из движков умных домов от себя рекомендую Home Assistant. Основная причина: там можно сделать весьма мощную систему вообще не написав ни одной строчки программного кода. Вся система настраивается через конфиги. ZigBee поддерживается "из коробки" через интеграцию zigbee2mqtt.

Comment: Спасибо, смотрю на OpenHub так знаком с Java, мне бы сейчас только определиться со свистком, смотрю CC2531 но не знаю так как это чисто Китай, не подведёт ли он в самый важный момент ;)

Comment: Оно всё сейчас Китай  Но Китай Китаю рознь. У меня в умном доме много Китая нормально работает...